# renaming files using adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

I want to rename a file on my android device (running CyanogenMod 11) using the adb shell. I have access to the phone via adb, but when I go to the directory where the file is located and try to rename it with `mv ./file.old ./file.new` I get `mv ./file.old failed, Read-only file system`. Tried the same with `su` but then I get `/system/bin/sh: su: not found`

Do I need to change something on my phone or somewhere else?

Comment: Apparently the file you are trying to rename is either on a read-only partition, or not writable by adb's "shell" user account.  Stock devices do not provide any means of escalating to root.

Comment: The device runs CyanogenMod, so afaik I should have root access, but I might be wrong.

Comment: if you have root access you should be able to rename it, or you should be able to `chmod` or `chown` that file and then rename it

Comment: I try to `chmod 755 file.old`, but I just get `Unable to chmod file.old: Read-only file system` So it seems like I somehow don't have root-access since I always get `/system/bin/sh: sudo: not found` when trying the same with `sudo`.

Comment: You need to mount the filesystem read/write first. Try `adb shell su -c busybox mount -o remount,rw /system` before running any command to modify system files.

Comment: Ok, sorry guys, seems like I don't have root access yet. I own the oneplus one which, although ships with cyanogenmod, isn't shipped rooted. So I've to root it first and then try it again.

Answer (score 2):

You should first mount `system` as rw

```
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
mv ./file.old ./file.new
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You cannot rename system file directly, if it's a system file, you'll need superuser permission and you'll have to make the file system read-write.
Second, Look on your phone as soon as you type su and Grant permission from phone.

Comment: when I try to rename the file with `su mv` my phone doesn't ask for permission. Still only `/system/bin/sh: su: not found`

Comment: execute adb root command from a PC terminal to get adb root access, all ROM doesn't accept this command.

Comment: I tried `adb root mv /filepath/file.old /filepath/file.new` which I get the error message `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`. My phone was shipped with CM, so albeit it uses CM it's not rooted. I guess when I fix this, the rest of the commands will work as well.