# Android - Rename file via sideload?

Tags: android, linker, adb, rom, sideloading

In an effort to get a WiFi adapter working I  was following  instructions on replacing a file called 'linker' in system/bin. Before copying the new linker file you gave I renamed my old one to linker2 because I wanted to be able to revert if needed.

After I renamed linker to linker2 my phone said I didn't have root anymore and I couldn't rename the file back.

I restarted and now am encountering an error that prevents booting. I'm in Android System Recovery with options:

- reboot system now
- apply update from ADB
- wipe data/factory reset
- wipe cache partition
- reboot to bootloader
- power down view
- recovery logs
- apply update from sdcard

If I select 'apply update via ADB' I can use ADB from my laptop, but seems the only thing I can do is sideload a file. Is it possible for me to sideload and execute a simple script to rename that file back to linker instead of linker2?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832507/renaming-files-using-adb-shell) thread might help you.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately not. I cannot access a full shell. The only command that works via ADB is sideload.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in your computer and rename it from there, then, put it in the adb folder and do "adb push linker /location/for/linker". Hopefully that should solve it, also, do not forget to search before you post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up doing a full wipe. However, I was not able to see the device connected to my computer in recovery console unless I select 'apply update from ADB'. At that point, I could only sideload via ADB. I was not allowed to push or anything else. I did try sideloading a custom script to rename the file back but unfortunately was not able to get it working due to 'signature verification failed'. My bootloader was not unlocked and 'reboot to boatloader' would not work. I don't think I really had any other option than a full reset.